# ASUS HyperX M.2 x4 only the first device is visible under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dell, nvme

I have a Dell T320 with an ASUS HyperX M.2 x4 PCI-e card (in a PCI-e 3.0 x16 socket), and two Samsung 970 PRO in it (in slot 1 and slot 2 of Hyper M.2), but under Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS I only see the NVMe device inserted in solot 1 of Hyper M.2. I tried with `fdisk -l`, and `nvme list` tools.

Is there any trick to get the slot 2 working under Linux?

```
root@server:/root# nvme list
Node             SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev
---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme0n1     S463NF0K820143E      Samsung SSD 970 PRO 512GB                1           0.00   B / 512.11  GB    512   B +  0 B   1B2QEXP7
```

Comment: Move _both_ SSDs to different slots, then run `nvme list` again and compare the output.

Comment: Thanks, i will tomorrow morning, now i only have remote access to Linux and iDrac as well

Comment: We tried to having only one NVMe in second slot, and it was not recognized. It seems, this server (Dell T320) does not support x4x4x4x4 PCI-e mode on a x16 bus, which seems required to work for this card. Even though not found a clear list which mainboards/CPUs support this mode. So we needed to use two cards at the end... :(

Answer (score 2):

You may need to setup PCIe slot bifurcation, i.e. split x16 link to four x4 links.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use different slots combination on the card.
Based on this it should be with Slot_1 and Slot_3 -> https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1037507/?fbclid=IwAR2usDcn9hBU5qnKogNmWSVJg5azaPW_-hRKXQ5__JVSLA4KEOyBDwlEKN8